# ML Kit FaceDetection CameraSourcePreview is null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I have implemented the Firebase ML Kit for face-detection in my app. In the demo app, where I created a new Firebase project and added the google json file its working fine. But in the existing app (the one on the playstore app) it returns null for the `CameraSourcePreview` and `graphicOverlay` declaration. Below is the code that I am using in my app:

```
public class ChildModeActivity extends BaseActivity {
    private CameraSource cameraSource = null;
    private CameraSourcePreview preview;
    private GraphicOverlay graphicOverlay;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_child_mode);       
        preview = (CameraSourcePreview) findViewById(R.id.childCameraPreview);
        if (preview == null) {
            Log.d("TAG_FACE", "Preview is null");
        }
        graphicOverlay = (GraphicOverlay) findViewById(R.id.childFaceOverlay);
        if (graphicOverlay == null) {
            Log.d("TAG_FACE", "graphicOverlay is null");
        }       
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
        createCameraSource();
        } else {
            getRuntimePermissions();
        }
    }
    private void startCameraSource() {
        if (cameraSource != null) {
            try {
                if (preview == null) {
                    Log.d("TAG_FACE", "resume: Preview is null");
                }
                if (graphicOverlay == null) {
                    Log.d("TAG_FACE", "resume: graphOverlay is null");
                }
                preview.start(cameraSource, graphicOverlay);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("TAG_FACE", "Unable to start camera source.", e);
                cameraSource.release();
                cameraSource = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void createCameraSource() {
        try {
        // If there's no existing cameraSource, create one.
            if (cameraSource == null) {
                Log.i("TAG_FACE", "Camera Source is Null so create new one");
                cameraSource = new CameraSource(this, graphicOverlay);
                cameraSource.setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
            //  cameraSource = new CameraSource(this);
                cameraSource.setMachineLearningFrameProcessor(new FaceDetectionProcessor());
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.i("TAG_FACE" , " Create Camera Source Exception:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

In the above code my `BaseActivity` extends `AppCompatActivity`.

Whenever I run the app, I am getting that "Preview is null" and "graphicOverlay is null" in the log. The preview is not showing.

Comment: Camera preview is null received because of multiple view issue. After added the Camerapreview in multiple layout views issue is fixed. Sorry, it was a stupid mistake done by me.

Comment: I have raised the another question reg ML Kit Face Detection. I have to run Face detection using ML kit in background service class. pls have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53682721/firebase-ml-kit-how-to-run-face-detection-in-background-as-service